# Attempting to edit fax number in AD for all users with a fax number listed

Tags: powershell

I will first begin on saying I am very new to PowerShell and my question is probably very easy to solve. All I am trying to do is use `Get-QADuser` and grab all ad users with a fax number listed, once I have that I simply want to add a "1" to all those users at the beginning of said fax number. I am trying to go based on the code I see below, but I don't believe this is exactly what I need. Any and all help is appreciated!

```
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot "abc.com/ABC/Users" -LdapFilter '(facsimileTelephoneNumber=555-555-1234)' | Foreach-Object{Set-QADuser -Identity $_ -ObjectAttributes @{facsimileTelephoneNumber='555-555-4321'}}
```

Comment: You say you are trying to go based on that code, what have you tried? What error did you get? Show us what you have done, not just what you found online.

Comment: sorry, the problem is I cant really test anything as this is a production environment and just need to get some code over to the customer so they can take a look at it and have it approved.

Comment: The regular built-in AD cmdlets have a -WhatIf switch on the ones that do 'Sets'. Can't remember if the QAD ones do off the cuff, but you could try: `Get-QADUser -SearchRoot "abc.com/ABC/Users" -LdapFilter '(facsimileTelephoneNumber=555-555-1234)' | Select -First 5 |
 Foreach-Object{Set-QADuser -Identity $_ -ObjectAttributes @{facsimileTelephoneNumber='1-555-555-4321'}} -WhatIf`  If you get an error, nothing will get set, if it changes, that would only only change the first 5, but if there is in fact a `-WhatIf` switch it should print to the console what would happen without taking action

Comment: @trebleCode That `-WhatIf` needs to be inside the loop, so the last `}` should come after the `-WhatIf` not before it.

Comment: Yep you're right, good catch @themadtechnician!

Answer (score 0):

Without using Quest tools, you could do something like below.
The assumption here is that you would like to add the `1` to a formatted faxnumber, so I'm going for prepending `1-` to the existing number, but ONLY if the existing number does not already start with `1` or `+` (used for country codes).

Right now, the `-WhatIf` switch will make the code only output what WOULD happen so you can investigate if this is what you really want.
If you're happy with the output, remove the `-WhatIf` switch so the code actually updates the faxnumbers where applicable.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# get all users in the specified OU that have a fax number
Get-ADUser -LdapFilter '(facsimileTelephoneNumber=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=UserAccounts,DC=YourDomain,DC=com' -Properties 'Fax' | ForEach-Object {
    # test if the number starts with a '1' or a '+' and if that is NOT the case, prepend '1-' to the number
    if ($_.Fax -notmatch '^[+1].*') {
        # the faxnumber does not already start with "1" or "+"
        $newFax = '1-{0}' -f $_.Fax
        Write-Host "Setting Faxnumber to '$newFax' for user $($_.Name)"
        # remove the '-WhatIf' if you are sure the number may be changed
        $_ | Set-ADUser -Fax $newFax -WhatIf
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Faxnumber '$($_.Fax)' for user $($_.Name) remains unchanged" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}
```

<sup>*P.s. The `-SearchBase` is the `DistinghuishedName` property of the OU the users are in. Start 'Active Directory Users and Computers' (ADUC), select and right-click the wanted OU and choose 'Properties'. In tab 'Attributes' scroll down to `distinghuishedName`, double click and copy from there.*</sup>