# Fax number update script, how to reverse?

Tags: powershell

I have created a script that would allow for the addition of the values "1-" to the beginning of our current AD fax numbers. I am running this in a test environment and the script runs exactly as I want it. I am looking for a failback and I can't seem to get that script to remove the "1-" it instead removes the 1 from the beginning and the final number from the end of the fax so the output looks like this: "-(###)-###-###" instead of looking like the correct number format "(###)-###-####"

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {facsimileTelephoneNumber -like "*"} -Properties facsimileTelephoneNumber| foreach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_ –replace @{facsimileTelephoneNumber="1-$($_.facsimileTelephoneNumber)"}}


Get-ADUser -Filter {facsimileTelephoneNumber -like "*"} -Properties facsimileTelephoneNumber| foreach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_ –replace @{facsimileTelephoneNumber="$(($_.facsimileTelephoneNumber).Substring(1,($_.facsimileTelephoneNumber.length) -2 ))"}}
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what you are telling it to do. PowerShell arrays (and string indexes) are zero-origin.

Answer (score 1):

Following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367720/9898643) to your previous question where the `1-` is **added** to the fax number, this is how you can reverse that.

I see in your question you are trying to do it all as one-liners, thereby skipping all possibility to check your code step-by-step. Using the first oneliner in your question also prepends `1-` to simply **every faxnumber found**, regardless if it is needed or not.

Especially when just starting PowerShell, writing things out is a good thing.

Having said that, here's the code to remove the leading `1-` from faxnumbers

```
# Remove leading '1-' from ADUsers faxnumbers

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# get all users in the specified OU that have a fax number starting with '1-'
Get-ADUser -LdapFilter '(facsimileTelephoneNumber=1-*)' -SearchBase 'OU=UserAccounts,DC=YourDomain,DC=com' -Properties 'Fax' | ForEach-Object {
    # using Substring() to remove the first two characters. See: https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html
    $newFax = ($_.Fax).Substring(2)
    Write-Host "Setting Faxnumber to '$newFax' for user $($_.Name)"
    # remove the '-WhatIf' if you are sure the number may be changed
    $_ | Set-ADUser -Fax $newFax -WhatIf
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You are so right about the oneliner part. Lately I'm seeing a lot of questions where people overcomplicate their scripts by doing everything on a single line of code.